# translating uniqueness quantifier algorithmically

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, quantifiers

Given a claim with a uniqueness quantifier $\exists$!, such as: $$\forall x \exists!y \ P(x,y)  $$

A standard translation that uses $\forall$ and $\exists$ only (there are several possible ones) is:

$$\forall x \exists y \ \big(P(x,y) \wedge \forall z(P(x, z) \supset z = y )\big)$$

I have two questions. The first involves expanding the predicate. If instead we have a three-place predicate and a repeated variable:
$$\forall x \exists!y \ P(x,y,y)  $$

is this a sound translation?

$$\forall x \exists y \big(P(x,y,y) \wedge \forall z(P(x,z,z) \supset z = y    )\big) $$

... or do would I need to split up the $z$s like this?

$$\forall x \exists y \big(P(x,y,y) \wedge \forall u \forall v(P(x,u,v) \supset u = v \wedge v= y   ) \big) $$

This seems like it covers more cases than it needs to, given that the $P(x,y,y)$ term on the left already eliminates cases where $u \not= v$.

My real question involves a more general algorithm for generating translations in cases of this sort. Given metavariables $\alpha, \beta, \delta$ that can stand for either $x$ or $y$, suppose we have a formula of this sort: 
$$\forall x \exists!y \ P(\alpha, \beta, \delta)  $$

is this a sound method of generating a translation?

first, write "$\forall x \exists y \big( P(\alpha, \beta, \delta) \wedge \forall z(\ \ )\big)$"

then, inside the brackets after $\forall z$:

if $\alpha =y$, add "$(P(z, \beta, \delta) \supset z = y)$"

if $\beta =y$, add "$(P(\alpha, z, \delta) \supset z = y)$"

if $\delta =y$, add "$(P(\alpha, \beta, z) \supset z = y)$"

... with conjunction $\wedge$ between terms if you wind up with more than one, and replacing the metavariables with $x$ or $y$ as appropriate. Is this sound or have I missed the plot somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

Consider your formula $\forall x \exists!y \ P(x,y,y)$, and suppose that we could rewrite it like this:

\begin{align}
&\forall x \\
&\quad \text{let }\Phi(\alpha) = P(x,\alpha,\alpha) \text{ in}\\
&\quad \exists! y\ \Phi(y)
\end{align}

Then, your transcription should generate something like this:

\begin{align}
&\forall x \\
&\quad \text{let }\Phi(\alpha) = P(x,\alpha,\alpha) \text{ in}\\
&\quad \exists y\ \Big(\Phi(y) \land \forall z\ \Phi(z) \to z = y\Big)
\end{align}

and then after inlining $\Phi$ you get the desired result.

In this light $$\forall x \exists y \big(P(x,y,y) \wedge \forall u \forall v(P(x,u,v) \supset u = v \wedge v= y   ) \big) \tag{$\clubsuit$}$$ is **not** equivalent to $$\forall x \exists!y \ P(x,y,y).\tag{$\spadesuit$}$$ Consider $\Omega = \{0,1\}$ and $P = \{(0,0,0),(0,0,1),(1,1,0),(1,1,1)\}$, then $(\clubsuit)$ is false, while $(\spadesuit)$ is true.

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$

Comment: isn't $(\spadesuit)$ false though?

Comment: @mips Do you see any $y$ other than $y = x$ that would satisfy $P(x,y,y)$?

Comment: haha, sorry, I was reading the quantifiers backwards, classic mistake. Thanks.